# Workaround for Series messing up Inactive[Integrate]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, series-expansion, hold

**Bug introduced in 10.0**

---

`Series` does not correctly construct expansions of inactive `Integrate`:

```
Series[Inactive[Integrate][x^a, {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

> [image]

It pulls stuff that depends on the integration variable `x`, *outside* of the integral.

Is there a workaround?  Is this a bug, or intended behavior?

**Edit**: Reported as bug, case 3895925

Comment: Well, it's incorrect, so I've got to think it's not intended.

Comment: The problem is that due to `Inactive` the `Series` code treats the integral as any other function, hence takes derivatives of it.  It is instructive to replace `Integrate` by `f`.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround

```
taylor[f_, x_List, x0_List, n_Integer] := 
 Sum[1/i! Nest[(x - x0).# &, D[f, {x, i}] /. Thread[x -> x0], i], {i, 0, n}]

taylor[Inactive[Integrate][x^a, {x, 0, 1}], {a}, {0}, 2]
```

[image]