# Approximating a function as a truncated series before integrating

Tags: numerical-integration, series-expansion

How can I compute a series of an expression in numerical integral?

For example, I want to ignore the powers of `b` that are higher than 3, before evaluating the integral.

```
f[x] = (b + x)^5; NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + Sqrt[f[x]]], [x, 2, 3]]
```

I know that I should specify `b` in order to solve it, but I need to relinquish the higher powers of `b` before solving it.

Comment: (1) It is not clear what is wanted here. A simple input and desired output would help. (2) What code there is will not even parse, let alone run.That sort of thing should be checked before posting.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) and [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := (b + x)^5;
ii = Inactive[NIntegrate][1/Sqrt[x^2 + Sqrt[f[x]]], {x, 2, 3}]
Activate@Sum[(D[ii, {b, k}] /. b -> 0)/k!*b^k, {k, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The system has some knowledge how to handle inactivated calculus operators.  `Series[ii, {b, 0, 3}]`, however, failed to give the correct series expansion.

*Remark:* The above works with `Integrate` as well, and for the particular example, the coefficient can be computed exactly with `Integrate`.

Comment: I complain about `Series` messing up `Inactive[Integrate]` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140344/workaround-for-series-messing-up-inactiveintegrate)

Comment: It does not work for Mathematica 9, but in 10.4.1 it is true.
Thank you